# Ubuntu 18.04 No sound

Tags: 18.04

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on my Lenevo thinkpad but my sound is not working. I tried many solutions given on different links but not working for me. If someone can help me to solve it, it will be a great help for me.

Thank You
Shyam

Comment: Have you tried to follow any Ubuntu troubleshooting documentation? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure (at the very least step 4 contains detail that will tell you what hardware (chipsets) exist in your thinkpad, which allow searches online, plus allow us to know your box & provide meaningful help.

Comment: I checked it says no cards found however I have install alsamixer from the terminal. Is there any simple way to solve the issue? I tried some of suggestion but then typing command without knowing has crashed my Ubuntu,